# sql query taking huge time to execute mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i have following query

```
SELECT 
       b.ledger_name, 
       a.trans_id, 
       a.voucher_id, 
       a.r_trans_id, 
       a.voucher_number, 
       date_format(a.trans_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as trans_date,        
       a.trans_type as voucher_type, 
       a.trans_type_name, 

       case when Sum(a.trans_amount) > 0 then round(abs(Sum(a.trans_amount)),2) else 0 end as amount_cr, 
       case when Sum(a.trans_amount) < 0 then round(abs(Sum(a.trans_amount)),2) else 0  end as amount_dr 
FROM   transaction_ledger AS a 
       LEFT JOIN ledger_master AS b 
              ON b.company_code = a.company_code
                 AND b.ledger_code = a.ledger_ref_code 
WHERE  a.ledger_code = '31' 
       AND a.company_code = '65370928-9ee1-40f6-ac38-e7a381908fd9'
       AND a.trans_date BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2014-01-31'
       AND a.trans_type_name in('Sales', 'Purchase', 'Receipt', 'Payment', 'Journal' ,'Credit Note', 'Debit Note', 'Contra')
GROUP  BY b.ledger_name, 
          a.trans_id, 
          a.voucher_id, 
          a.r_trans_id, 
          a.voucher_number, 
          a.trans_date, 
          a.company_code, 
          a.narration, 
          a.trans_type, 
          a.trans_type_name 
ORDER  BY date_format(a.trans_date,'%Y-%m-%d'), a.voucher_number;
```

The table transaction_ledger has about 200,000 records. Above query takes too much time to execute. I have also created index wherever needed. What could be causing the delay ?

Following are some details :

Index

`transaction_ledger` ( `r_trans_id` , `trans_date` , `ledger_code` , `ledger_ref_code` , `company_code` , `trans_type` , `trans_type_name` )

`ledger_master(ledger_code, company_code)`

EXPLAIN

1  SIMPLE a ALL                     92553 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE b ALL PRIMARY,ledger_code 2338

Comment: Math functions are resourceful! Probably that would be the case.. `BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2014-01-31'` also could be the case.

Comment: Sometimes a JOIN query will create a temporary table and that might be the problem; you can prepend `EXPLAIN` to the query (before SELECT) which will tell you what the database will do on that query.

Comment: Why do you need to do an order by with formatting in it? for e.g. why do you use `ORDER  BY date_format(a.trans_date,'%Y-%m-%d')` instead of `ORDER  BY a.trans_date`?

Comment: removed order by still no changes.

Comment: How much is exactly 'too much time'? Because 200.000 records + LEFT JOIN + conditions + calculations is not a typical speedy query

Comment: You say you've created indexes wherever needed, but you don't know why your query is slow, so what indexes do you actually have?

Comment: @carexcer : around 2 mins.

Comment: @GoatCO : i have added index details in the question

Comment: `ON a.company_code = '65370928-9ee1-40f6-ac38-e7a381908fd9'` Looks like a typo; you already restricted ON a.company_code in the where clause.

Comment: @wildplasser: yup that was a typo. i have edited

Answer (score 0):

I would have an index on your ledger_master table ON ( ledger_code )

ON your transaction_ledger table, you would want columns that best fit the needs of your query.  In this case

( company_code, ledger, trans_date, trans_type_name )

also, your "ON" condition for the left join had the company code there AND the where clause, you should only need it in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT 
      b.ledger_name, 
      a.trans_id, 
      a.voucher_id, 
      a.r_trans_id, 
      a.voucher_number, 
      date_format(a.trans_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as trans_date,        
      a.trans_type as voucher_type, 
      a.trans_type_name, 
      case when Sum(a.trans_amount) > 0 then round(abs(Sum(a.trans_amount)),2) else 0 end as amount_cr, 
      case when Sum(a.trans_amount) < 0 then round(abs(Sum(a.trans_amount)),2) else 0  end as amount_dr 
   FROM   
      transaction_ledger AS a 
         LEFT JOIN ledger_master AS b 
            a.ledger_ref_code = b.ledger_code 
   WHERE
          a.company_code = '65370928-9ee1-40f6-ac38-e7a381908fd9'
      AND a.ledger_code = '31' 
      AND a.trans_date BETWEEN '2010-04-01' AND '2014-01-31'
      AND a.trans_type_name in ('Sales', 'Purchase', 'Receipt', 'Payment', 'Journal' ,'Credit Note', 'Debit Note', 'Contra')
   GROUP BY 
      b.ledger_name, 
      a.trans_id, 
      a.voucher_id, 
      a.r_trans_id, 
      a.voucher_number, 
      a.trans_date, 
      a.company_code, 
      a.narration, 
      a.trans_type, 
      a.trans_type_name 
   ORDER BY 
      date_format(a.trans_date,'%Y-%m-%d'), a.voucher_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can speed this up with an additional index on `transaction_ledger`:

```
transaction_ledger(ledger_code, company_code, trans_type_name, trans_date)
```

Note that this is one index with four columns, not four columns with one index.

In addition, you don't need the company comparison in the left outer join`-- you have it in the`where`clause (this doesn't affect performance but it cleans up the query).  So change the`from` clause to:

```
FROM   transaction_ledger a left outer join
       ledger_master b 
       ON b.ledger_code = a.ledger_ref_code
```

As for explaining what could be causing the delay, you would need to do an `explain` on the query and show the results in the question.

Comment: this is the EXPLAIN output : 1 SIMPLE a ALL 92553 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort 1 SIMPLE b ALL PRIMARY,ledger_code 2338

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could avoid the use of `LEFT JOIN`, because one condition can be deleted and the other you can test it on the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT                    

b.ledger_name, 
               a.trans_id, 
               a.voucher_id, 
               a.r_trans_id, 
               a.voucher_number, 
               date_format(a.trans_date,'%d-%m-%Y') as trans_date,        
               a.trans_type as voucher_type, 
               a.trans_type_name, 

               case when Sum(a.trans_amount) > 0 then round(Sum(a.trans_amount),2) else 0 end as amount_cr,
               case when Sum(a.trans_amount) < 0 then round(abs(Sum(a.trans_amount)),2) else 0  end as amount_dr 
        FROM   transaction_ledger AS a, ledger_master AS b 
        WHERE  a.ledger_code = '31' 
               AND a.company_code = '65370928-9ee1-40f6-ac38-e7a381908fd9'
               AND a.trans_type_name in('Sales', 'Purchase', 'Receipt', 'Payment', 'Journal' ,'Credit Note', 'Debit Note', 'Contra')
               AND b.ledger_code = a.ledger_ref_code  --this was in the join
               AND a.trans_date > '2010-04-01' 
               AND a.trans_date <'2014-01-31'

        GROUP  BY b.ledger_name, 
                  a.trans_id, 
                  a.voucher_id, 
                  a.r_trans_id, 
                  a.voucher_number, 
                  a.trans_date, 
                  a.company_code, 
                  a.narration, 
                  a.trans_type, 
                  a.trans_type_name 
        ORDER  BY date_format(a.trans_date,'%Y-%m-%d'), a.voucher_number) as x
```

Further, you can replace the BETWEEN with 2 conditions, and set the conditions of the where ordered by restrictiveness (first more restrictive) because you only have AND conditions, and if the first isn't satisfied then isn't necessary to continue testing the others.

**EDIT:**
You also can avoid one of the `abs()`, but the improvement will be quite little.

Comment: i need the left join to get names from ledger_master table.

Comment: You don't need because you can include the ledger_master table on the from clause. Try the update query I've posted.

Comment: I've updated the query, this one has better performance but I don't know how to improve it more. I hope this be useful